# Finding mode and median in Javascript error

Tags: mode, median

I have been working on a coderbyte problem for the past two days. I thought I finally had it buy for some reason this I keep getting an error.

```
function comparemedianandmode(arr){

    function findmode(arr){
        mapping = {};
        mode = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(!mapping[arr[i]]){
                mapping[arr[i]] = 0; 
            }
            mapping[arr[i]] += 1;
        }    
        for(prop in mapping){
            if(mapping[prop] > mode){
               var mode = parseInt(prop);
            }
        } 

    }

    function findmedian(arr){
        arr.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
        if(arr.length % 2 === 0){
            var median = (arr[(arr.length/2)-1] + arr[arr.length/2])/2;
        }
        else{
            var median = arr[(arr.length - 1)/2];
        }

    }
    var answer = (median === mode) ? 1 : 0;
return answer
    }
```

When I try `comparemedianandmode([1,2,3,3,3,4,5])` I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: median is not defined
```

Must be something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out

**EDIT**

```
New Code:
function comparemedianandmode(arr){
var mode;
var median;


function findmode(arr){
    mapping = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(!mapping[arr[i]]){
            mapping[arr[i]] = 0; 
        }
        mapping[arr[i]] += 1;
    }    
    for(prop in mapping){
        if(mapping[prop] > mode){
           var mode = parseInt(prop);
        }
    } 

}
var median 
function findmedian(arr){
    var median
    arr.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
    if(arr.length % 2 === 0){
        median = (arr[(arr.length/2)-1] + arr[arr.length/2])/2;
    }
    else{
        median = arr[(arr.length - 1)/2];
    }
}
var answer = (median === mode) ? 1 : 0;
return answer
}

comparemedianandmode([1,2,3,3,3,4,5])

=> 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a variable with `var` will limit its scope to the function in which it is being declared. You are declaring `median` that way inside `findmedian()` but then trying to access `median` outside of that function in the line that is assigning a value to `answer`.

Remove `var` from the lines where you are assigning `median` a value. At the top of `comparemedianandmode()` (your outermost function), declare `median`:

```
var median;
```

You have a function within a function, and that inner function is where you are declaring `median` but then you are trying to use it outside that inner function in this line:

```
var answer = (median === mode) ? 1 : 0;
```

Incidentally, you will have to do the same for `mode`.

Here's what it will look like after all that:

```
function comparemedianandmode(arr){

    var median;
    var mode;

    function findmode(arr){
        mapping = {};
        mode = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(!mapping[arr[i]]){
                mapping[arr[i]] = 0; 
            }
            mapping[arr[i]] += 1;
        }    
        for(prop in mapping){
            if(mapping[prop] > mode){
                mode = parseInt(prop);
            }
        } 
    }

    function findmedian(arr){
        arr.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
        if(arr.length % 2 === 0){
            median = (arr[(arr.length/2)-1] + arr[arr.length/2])/2;
        } else {
            median = arr[(arr.length - 1)/2];
        }
    }

    answer = (median === mode) ? 1 : 0;
    return answer;
}

console.log(comparemedianandmode([1,2,3,3,3,4,5]));
```

Comment: Why can't I just no use `var` within the function when defining mode and median. I thought that would define it globally?

Comment: No, it will not define it globally. It will define it for that function. It will only define it globally if it is not within a function.